# Ошибка; AttributeError at /info 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

Делаю комментарии на джанго, используя django-comments-xtd Во время создания шаблона возникается описанная в вопросе ошибка. Шаблон(как прописано в документации):

Шаблон(как прописано в документации):

```html
{% extends "layout/base.html" %}

{% load comments %}

{% block home %}

<body>

{% get_comment_count for object as comment_count %}
<div class="py-4 text-center">
  <a href="{% url 'blog:post-list' %}">Back to the post list</a>
  &nbsp;&sdot;&nbsp;
  {{ comment_count }} comment{{ comment_count|pluralize }}
  ha{{ comment_count|pluralize:"s,ve" }} been posted.
</div>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Ошибка происходит из-за это строки:

```
{% get_comment_count for object as comment_count %}
```

если ее убрать - страница будет отображаться, но что не так с этой строкой?

Как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

В той строке что произошла ошибка написано `for object as comment_count`, однако в Python правильной конструкцией является  не `for ... as ...`, а `for ... in ...` .
Замените `as` на `in`.

***Решение:***

```
{% get_comment_count for object in comment_count %}
```

Comment: теперь выдает другую ошибку:
TemplateSyntaxError at /info  third argument in 'get_comment_count' must be 'as'

Comment: А что храниться в `get_comment_count`?